# Getting map data not yet available using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am using ArcMap.

When adding imagery basemap everything works ok, until map is zoomed at 1:800 scale, then  the legend "Map data not available yet" appears, but in others PC it is possible to see images beyond this scale in the same zone.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems like a performance issue with ArcGIS Online services. Try renaming the ESRI folder in your local and roaming profile, and test it again. C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local and C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming

Comment: Problem solved, thanks @Yogi